# bootstrap 4 accordion not working correctly it work only for first element

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show">
      <div class="card-body">
        Lorem ipsum..
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
      <div class="card-body">
        Lorem ipsum..
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    Collapsible Group Item #3
                </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
      <div class="card-body">
        Lorem ipsum..
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this accordion code not working in my html project.
I tried too many time but failed to worked it successfully.

also tried w3school snippet above. first one is working very nice but whenever I am trying to collapse second one it not working. it will collapse for couple of milli seconds after that it will automatically get display none property.

I am also tried to active collapse via jquery but the result is same.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: no console error

Comment: Are you using bootstrap.js cdn link...or downloaded one?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljo273tu/) for you

I think you simply forget to include jQuery **before** the bootstrap script.

Simply check your imports, should look somehow like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and jQuery import on top of all that

Comment: it's work fine in another apps only not worked in my current project.

Comment: <!--jquery script load-->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!--Owl carousel script load-->
  <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <!--Propper script load here-->
        <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <!--Bootstrap v4 script load here-->
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Use script inserts that I have used in the fiddle and with exact same order

Comment: still the same problem. wait i upload this in live server then you will be clear what the actual problem was.

Comment: That sounds strange, because even your code snippet works just fine

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a problem with a path to your files "assest/js/", but this should have been fixed by using CDN scripts from my fiddle. And you have a typo in "assest" word, it's assets not asseSt

Comment: i this using jquery is working file because a already used so many function using jquery.  I upload it in live server .
here is the link

Comment: I unfortunately cannot see your link

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: thanks for your help . finally i got it. it's bootstrap js file problem while i use the cdn it works fine. thanks for your valuable time

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski here is an updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljo273tu/) with Bootstrap 4 Accordion example

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working.

But, Check if you have included all necessary files for bootstrap 4 and also jQuery if required.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                Collapsible Group Item #1 Works
            </a>
        </div> 
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show">
            <div class="card-body">
                Lorem ipsum..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
                Lorem ipsum..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse">
            <div class="card-body">
                Lorem ipsum..
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Checkout : [demo](https://codepen.io/kaleem-elahi/pen/aERqmx)**